# getResources Navigation for non-hierarchical pages

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

I'm using getResources to populate categorical image galleries from image pages with matching categories.

Categories are not pre-defined, but created by the user as the site grows.

To facilitate this, I created two multi-select TVs, one for the "image page" template and the other for the "gallery" template, with both using the same input values.

The getResources call filters and outputs the categorical index at the gallery level by matching like so:

```
&tvfilters=`tv-one-name==`%[[*tv-two]]%`
```

Now, I need to create sidebar navigation at the child level (the "image page" level) that matches the index built on the parent "gallery". Not sure if it's possible, since there's no hierarchical connection between parent/child.

I have tried a similar getResources call, but included [[*parents]] in the &parents param. I tried the same &tvfilters param value as above, and a variation like:

```
&tvFilters=`tv-one-name==%[[*tv-one]]%,tv-one-name==%[[*tv-two]]%`
```

Neither creates the correct list, though.

Any thoughts? Thanks and appreciation in advance!

For the sake of clarity, here is the first getResources call that creates the gallery:

```
[[!getResources?
  &debug=`1`
  &parents=`4,[[*id]]`
  &where=`{"template:=":17 "OR:template:=":18}`
  &includeTVs=`1`
  &includeContent=`1`
  &processTVs=`1`
  &showHidden=`1`
  &hideContainers=`1`
  &tpl=`imageThumb`
  &limit=`0`
  &depth=`5`
  &tvFilters=`imageCategory==%[[*galleryTagSelector]]%`
  &tagDelimiter=`||`
  &sortBy=`{"publishedon":"ASC"}`
]]
```

And here is the second call that I'm trying to use for the sidebar nav:

```
[[!getResources?
  &parents=`4,[[*parent]]`
  &where=`{"template:=":17 "OR:template:=":18}`
  &includeTVs=`1`
  &includeContent=`1`
  &processTVs=`1`
  &showHidden=`1`
  &hideContainers=`1`
  &tpl=`imageListTpl`
  &limit=`0`
  &depth=`5`
  &tvFilters=`imageCategory==%[[*imageCategory]]%,imageCategory==%[[*galleryTagSelector]]%`
  &tagDelimiter=`||`
  &sortBy=`{"publishedon":"ASC"}`
]]
```

Comment: is &where property separated by comma?

Comment: Nope, that's the correct usage.

As it turns out, getResources works for sites that are hierarchical. Since I'm relating pages together through the use of tags, rather than a hierarchy, getResources isn't the right solution. I would up accomplishing this using a GET function.